# Как разместить сайт в поддиректории url на локальном сервере?

Tags: apache

Есть в локалке сервер на убунте, имеет имя servername и есть на сервере апач, если зайти на servername, то можно увидеть, что апач работает. 
Мне нужно, чтобы виртуальные хосты были доступны по url servername/sitename.
Вот такой код в site-available к этому не привел:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName  servername/sitename
ServerAlias /sitename
DocumentRoot /var/www/sitename
<Directory /var/www/sitename>
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Если сделать вот так, то ожидаемо на servername вылазит сайтик.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName  servername
DocumentRoot /var/www/sitename
<Directory /var/www/sitename>
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html

Comment: Бинго! @Etki 
То, что доктор прописал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно ли я вас понял, что вы хотите доступ к сайту по URL http://servername/sitename ? Если да, то вам логичней было бы сделать

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/servername
<Directory /var/www/servername/sitename>
...
</Directory>
```

Comment: В целом да, правильней, но мне было нужно вот это:
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName servername
    Alias "/site" "/var/www/site"
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory /var/www/site>
        Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: Но еще раз подумавши, пришел к выводу, что ваш ответ в контексте вопроса абсолютно верен и решение работает.